# Trying to parse date using new Date(). but keep getting wrong results

Tags: javascript, date, strtotime

I am trying to parse a date string i get from php through ajax call(which is irrelevant for now) using new Date().

however i keep getting wrong results.

My string is `2013-05-09 20:56:17`

When i do

```
var something = new Date("2013-05-09 20:56:17");
alert(something.getMonth());
```

It keeps alerting 0

In my opinion for some reason new date cant parse this string.

Is there a way to specify the date format for new Date() in JS ?

My current solution is to import php's: `date()` and `strtotime()` and use them :

```
alert(date('m', strtotime("2013-05-09 20:56:17")));
```

This works however I have to use external js lib and I am pretty sure there is a better JS way to achieve that.

Comment: you should just try to use moment.js ( http://momentjs.com/ ) to parse your date and time. I bet it will save you a lot of time.

Comment: I believe that you're using a format that cannot be parsed. Take a look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Comment: Your code works fine for me (the alert is `4` which corresponds to May since January is `0`) using Chrome 26.

Comment: @asgm it didn't work for me when i tested it. so i wouldn't rely on this cross-browser.

Comment: To not have to rely on what format any implementation might actually parse or not, you should just pass the unix timestamp value from PHP to JS, multiply it by 1000 (because JS handles timestamps in microseconds), and then just use `new Date(123456789000)`.

Comment: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Comment: I am trying to avoid including more outside libs, other wise i would just import the php functions. i am trying to find a pure JS solution. ASGM no the code doesn't work. CBroe yea i know but i do not have the timestamp and unable to use it.  Ofir there must be some way to parse it.

Comment: So, I assume you don't have access to the php script?

Comment: correct assumption yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use slashes instead of hyphens, it works:

```
var something = new Date("2013/05/09 20:56:17");
alert(something.getMonth());
```

It's easy enough to replace any hyphens in a string with slashes first if you need to (say, if you were getting the date string from somewhere else):

```
var something = new Date("2013-05-09 20:56:17");
something = something.replace('-', '/');
```

It seems JavaScript's `Date` constructor doesn't recognize date formats with hyphens, or at least not that particular format.

Comment: Nope it doesnt work even with `/` with sleshes it returns 4 while the month is either 05 or 09... so nope. Thanks though

Comment: @NetaMeta `4` is the correct month number. indexing starts at `0`, so `0` is january, while `4` is may. this will be the case no matter what date string you give it (if you want it to reflect the real-life month number, just add 1). mdn is a good resource to look up this kind of information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: @NetaMeta it's as easy as this: `var month = something.getMonth() + 1;`

Answer (score 0):

Choose a different format specifier in PHP for your ajax dates.  The format you expect and the format expected by the javascript are different.

```
var something = new Date("2013-05-09T20:56:17");
```

Note the 'T' which appears as a literal separator and marks the beginning of time per ISO 8601

Reference for various [browser] javascript date formats

- [W3 DateTime](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime)
- [Microsoft IE DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff743760%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)
- [Mozilla [Firefox] DateTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)
- [Google DateJs](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/FormatSpecifiers)

And lastly, the PHP date format specifier list:

- [PHP Date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)
- [PHP DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Note the 'DATE_ISO8601'; but I suggest not using that at this time. Instead use 'DATE_ATOM' which may produce a date format more widely supported (comments suggest it makes iPhones happier and no issues with other browsers).

To use it in PHP:

```
$something = new DateTime('NOW');
echo $something->format('c');
echo $something->format(DateTime::ATOM);
```